# Why mysql query slow with simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

I'm having a tough time with a pretty simple query.  I've tried using explain but i've never found it very useful, or I don't understand it well enough to try and optimize my query.  The profile below shows it takes 4 seconds to send the data but i swear the query execution time is like 10-15 second total.  If i take out the join to the facility table then the query is fine.  The facility table only has 10 rows in it.

my query

```
SELECT 
    bill_payDate AS Date,
    facilityName 

FROM bill_pay
    JOIN bill_invoice ON bill_invID = bill_pay_bill_invID 
    JOIN facility ON facilityID = bill_inv_facilityID 

WHERE  
    bill_pay.bill_payDate BETWEEN '2014-02-16 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-16 23:59:59'
```

EXPLAIN:

```
id    select_type    table         type   possible_keys                                 key                   key_len    ref                                        rows    Extra
1     SIMPLE         facility      index  PRIMARY                                       PRIMARY               2          NULL                                       30      Using index
1     SIMPLE         bill_invoice  ref    PRIMARY,bill_inv_facilityID                   bill_inv_facilityID   4          sam_arenasports.facility.facilityID        179     Using where
1     SIMPLE         bill_pay      ref    bill_pay_bill_invID,bill_payDate,payinv_date  bill_pay_bill_invID   4          sam_arenasports.bill_invoice.bill_invID    1       Using where
```

Profile:

```
Status  Time
starting    0.000050
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000011
checking query cache for query  0.000054
checking permissions    0.000012
checking permissions    0.000010
checking permissions    0.000011
Opening tables  0.000034
System lock 0.000016
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000033
init    0.000031
optimizing  0.000021
statistics  0.000108
preparing   0.000026
executing   0.000011
Sending data    3.852001
end 0.000056
query end   0.000011
closing tables  0.000023
freeing items   0.000018
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000010
freeing items   0.000052
Waiting for query cache lock    0.000011
freeing items   0.000009
storing result in query cache   0.000010
logging slow query  0.000010
logging slow query  0.000073
cleaning up 0.000013
```

Query Performed in terminal....

```
| 2014-02-16 22:39:14 |
| 2014-02-16 22:39:24 |
| 2014-02-16 22:41:42 |
| 2014-02-16 22:42:16 |
| 2014-02-16 22:50:09 |
| 2014-02-16 22:56:54 |
+---------------------+
1265 rows in set (26.47 sec)

mysql>
```

Facility Table, 30 rows

--

### -- Table structure for table `facility`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facility` (
   `facilityID` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `facilityName` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityPhone` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityEmail` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilitywww` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facilityNick` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityEmailBcastBounce` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityAddress1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityAddress2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityCity` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityState` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityZip` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facilityCCbypass` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `facility_ccPartner` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facility_ccVendor` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facility_ccUser` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facility_ccPass` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facility_ccAcceptedTypes` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'visa,mastercard',
   `facilityTZ` varchar(60) DEFAULT 'PST8PDT',
   `facilityTaxID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `facilityActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `facilityMySAMVisible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `facilityMySAMSupport` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`facilityID`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
```

bill_pay Table, 1.4 million rows:

--

### -- Table structure for table `bill_pay`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bill_pay` (
  `bill_payID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bill_pay_customerID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bill_pay_bill_invID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bill_payMethod` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bill_payDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `bill_payAmount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `bill_payMethodInfo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_paySwipe` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bill_payCVV` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Credit card security code response',
  `bill_payModU` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bill_payPNRef` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bill_payAuth` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bill_payCCexp` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_payExplain` tinytext,
  `bill_payCheckType` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bill_payCCType` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bill_payID`),
  KEY `bill_pay_customerID` (`bill_pay_customerID`),
  KEY `bill_pay_bill_invID` (`bill_pay_bill_invID`),
  KEY `bill_payMethod` (`bill_payMethod`),
  KEY `bill_payDate` (`bill_payDate`),
  KEY `bill_payPNRef` (`bill_payPNRef`),
  KEY `bill_payModU` (`bill_payModU`),
  KEY `payinv_date` (`bill_pay_bill_invID`,`bill_payDate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1390369 ;
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this query directly from the MySQL terminal? You're dealing with a negligible number of rows, it seems like it should be fine though you could do with some indices on your other tables.

Comment: [This is a good read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html) if you want to understand output from `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I've added the results of running the query from the terminal.

Comment: I've read the help page from the mysql site many times... and other sites but thanks for the link.

Comment: 26 seconds for _that_? Ouch. "`If I take out the join to the facility table then the query is fine.`" Why is facility table included at all? It's not used in the select list or where clause. Seems to be extra. Maybe that's confusing your query optimizer.

Comment: Unless I haven't had enough coffee this morning, it looks like your query doesn't use the joined tables at all? This may be best left to an SQL guru, I'm an SQL idiot savant on a good day :)

Comment: I simplified the select portion of the query so it's not showing everything i'd like to select.  The facility table has the location, so yes, I'd like to include it.

Comment: You gave us a lot of information except for what is probably the most important: **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.

Comment: i added the table structures, indexes and row counts.  Keep in mind that If I don't join the facility table it's almost instantaneous.

Comment: I go for the 'suck-it-and-see' method when it comes to optimisation. (not great, I know)... Can you try dropping all indexes on bill_pay except for the PK and then add a compound key on (bill_pay_bill_invID,bill_payDate)? Also, this naming strategy would drive me nuts but hey, it's your party!

Comment: Unfortunately, i inherited the naming scheme.

Comment: i noticed facility.facilityID was a smallint(6) where bill_invoice.bill_inv_facilityID was an int(11).. i changed int(11) to match the small int and the query was fast.  Am I on to something?  Is there an issue with mysql using indexes with two different types?

Comment: No, there is no issue with MySql - if types of keys don't match, then MySql must cast one of them to another type, and this takes time.

Comment: weird.  well, i'll close this question.. not sure i feel confident that this is the problem but anywho.